# VBA saved a new file how to use this file for coding further

Tags: excel, vba

I saved an Excel file with a name of a dynamically changing cell value. E.g. `1Extract`, `2Extract`, `3Extract`, etc.

How do I activate this new work book for further coding, E.g. `windows(DynamicCellValueString & "Extract").Activate`?

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for something along these lines:

```
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=sPath & x & "extract" & ".xlsx", FileFormat:= _
```

xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
   ActiveWorkbook.Close False

sPath is defined at the beginning of the macro thus:  (on a mac...)

```
Dim sPath As String
```

sPath = MacScript("(path to desktop folder as string)")